# Issue in sharing a folder between Windows 8 host and CentOS running in a VM through virtualbox

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I have a `Windows 8` machine and I am running a `CentOS 6.7` `virtual machine` through `virtualbox`. I want to share a folder present in Windows 8 host machine with VM but I am having some issue. Here is what I did:

In my virtualbox VM settings went to the share folder section and added the folder from Windows 8 with selecting Auto-mount and permanent. Restarted my VM and can see the folder name coming up on my VM desktop. Now when I try to click open that folder in the VM I get error as `"You do not have the permission to access the content of this folder"` and it does not open.

What should I do to resolve this issue? And what could be the easiest way to share the folder and files under that folder from Windows 8 and CentOS VM?

**NOTE:** I also enabled drag and drop option under virtualbox to be bidirectional but when I drag my file from host Windows 8 to guest VM CentOS nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

After digging through I found the step I was missing. I needed to add my user to the vboxsf group. I added it the group and now I can see the contents of the folder.